# Some way to snap a screenshot and auto upload?

Tags: automation, screenshot

Is there anyway for design purposes that I can have son image host?

Currently if I need to share a desktop screenshot I have to:

1. open photoshop
2. Create new image
3. Past screen capture to new image
4. save fore web, sometime resize
5. then upload to an image host

Would be nice if there was something lightweight that would do this whole process in 1 sweep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.pict.com/software

Comment: Thank you that is a lifesaver, I didn't really think it existed =)

Comment: The domain above links to a parking page?

Comment: Another one bit the dust, sorry. It was operational in Aug 2009